# Getting the bounding box of QTextEdit selection

Tags: python, selection, pyside, bounding-box, qtextedit

I'm trying to get the bounding box of a series of text selections stored in a list. The bounding box is the smallest rectangle that can contain the whole selection. Each item in the list has a start and end point measured in characters from the beginning of the `QTextEdit` window and also a letter identifier. `QTextEdit.cursorRect(cursor)` should do this, but is producing nonsensical box dimensions:

```
id: A -- PySide.QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1, 10)
id: B -- PySide.QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1, 10)
id: C -- PySide.QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1, 10)
```

The selections all start at different points so (0,0) is not correct in viewpoint coordinates. Also, some of them span several lines so the width and height should vary. The problem may be that the cursor is in a loop and I don't set it with `setTextCursor` until after the loop finishes. I do this because I'm also rendering the selections as highlights. How can I get `cursorRect` to work correctly or otherwise get a separate bounding box for each selection? Here is the code:

```
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

db = ((5,8,'A'),(20,35,'B'),(45,60,'C')) # start, end, and identifier of highlights

class TextEditor(QTextEdit):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        text="This is example text that is several lines\nlong and also\nstrangely broken up and can be\nwrapped."
        self.setText(text)
        for n in range(0,len(db)):
            row = db[n]
            startChar = row[0]
            endChar = row[1]
            id = row[2]

            cursor = self.textCursor()
            cursor.setPosition(startChar)
            cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.NextCharacter, QTextCursor.KeepAnchor, endChar-startChar)

            rect = self.cursorRect(cursor)
            print("id: %s -- %s" % (id,str(rect)))

            charfmt = cursor.charFormat()
            charfmt.setBackground(QColor(Qt.yellow))
            cursor.setCharFormat(charfmt)
        cursor.clearSelection()
        self.setTextCursor(cursor)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    editor = TextEditor()
    editor.show()
    app.exec_()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**EDIT 1**:

Here is the text from the program. I'll use CAPS for the highlighted text:

```
This IS example text THAT IS SEVERAL lines
loNG AND ALSO
STRangely broken up and can be
wrapped.
```

Let's assume every character is 10 pixels by 10 pixels. The "IS " starts 5 characters in and extends for 3 characters (including a space at the end). So, the upper left corner of the "I" would be at x=50,y=0. The bottom right corner of the space would be at x=80,y=10. If the bounding rectangle is given in coordinates, it would be (50,0,80,10). If the bounding rectangle is given in starting coordinates and size, it would be (50,0,30,10).

On the second line is a highlight that continues to the third line. Its leftmost character is the "S" at the start of line 3, which is at x=0. Its rightmost character is the "O" in "ALSO" which ends at x=130. Its topmost line is the second line, which begins at y=10. Its bottom most line is the third line, which ends at y=30. So, the bounding box would be (0,10,130,30) in coordinates or (0,10,130,20) in starting point and size.

Comment: I have a curiosity, if a selection covers several lines that rectangle you want to get?

Comment: Thank you for your question. I've added an example at the end. Hopefully it clarifies what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: I do not understand your explanation for several lines, please give a more clear example please.

Comment: When you select several lines the selection is not rectangular, the coordinates and I am understanding but what is the ark and high. I think the correct thing would be a set of QRect, one for each line.

Comment: In the short term, I would be happy with the QRect of the starting character and last character of each highlight. I don't understand though why I'm getting the same rectangle all the time.

Comment: I've added a more detailed example.

Comment: cursorRect () does not do that, ie your second case, from what I understand you want the coordinate (x, y) of the initial and final letter of the selection. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, the x,y of the initial and final letter of the selections as stored in the database (db). If you look at the first item in db, I want the (x,y) of the 5th character and the 8th character, which may change with scrolling and word wrap.

Comment: see my answer :P

Comment: @davideps. Your description of the multi-line selection seems wrong. The bounding box must start at the *beginning* of the second line (so that the "S" at the beginning of the third line is included), and end at the "o" of the third line (so the "O" at the end of the second line is included). You should also note that changing the char-format can reset the layout of the document - so any geometric calculations made at the same time will not be reliable in the general case. Finally, note that the cursor rect is in *viewport coordinates*, so you probably need to allow for that as well.

Comment: @ekhumoro, you are correct. I've fixed my multi-line example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is a first effort at finding the bounding boxes for all the highlighted sections specified by the information from the database. To make it clear exactly what each bounding box covers, the example script displays a corresponding rubber band. Here is what the results look like:

[image]

Resizing the window will automatically re-calculate the boxes according to the current word-wrapping. Note that this may mean several of the boxes overlap each other if the window becomes very small.

I have implemented this as a separate method, because changes to the char format can potentially re-set the document layout. It is therefore more reliable to calculate the boxes in a second pass. And of course, this also allows for dynamic re-calculation whenever the window is resized.

```
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

db = ((5,8,'A'),(20,35,'B'),(45,60,'C')) # start, end, and identifier of highlights

class TextEditor(QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        text="This is example text that is several lines\nlong and also\nstrangely broken up and can be\nwrapped."
        self.setText(text)
        cursor = self.textCursor()
        for n in range(0,len(db)):
            row = db[n]
            startChar = row[0]
            endChar = row[1]
            id = row[2]
            cursor.setPosition(startChar)
            cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.NextCharacter, QTextCursor.KeepAnchor, endChar-startChar)
            charfmt = cursor.charFormat()
            charfmt.setBackground(QColor(Qt.yellow))
            cursor.setCharFormat(charfmt)
        cursor.clearSelection()
        self.setTextCursor(cursor)

    def getBoundingRect(self, start, end):
        cursor = self.textCursor()
        cursor.setPosition(end)
        last_rect = end_rect = self.cursorRect(cursor)
        cursor.setPosition(start)
        first_rect = start_rect = self.cursorRect(cursor)
        if start_rect.y() != end_rect.y():
            cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.StartOfLine)
            first_rect = last_rect = self.cursorRect(cursor)
            while True:
                cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.EndOfLine)
                rect = self.cursorRect(cursor)
                if rect.y() < end_rect.y() and rect.x() > last_rect.x():
                    last_rect = rect
                moved = cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.NextCharacter)
                if not moved or rect.y() > end_rect.y():
                    break
            last_rect = last_rect.united(end_rect)
        return first_rect.united(last_rect)

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.edit = TextEditor(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)
        self.boxes = []

    def showBoxes(self):
        while self.boxes:
            self.boxes.pop().deleteLater()
        viewport = self.edit.viewport()
        for start, end, ident in db:
            rect = self.edit.getBoundingRect(start, end)
            box = QRubberBand(QRubberBand.Rectangle, viewport)
            box.setGeometry(rect)
            box.show()
            self.boxes.append(box)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.showBoxes()
        super().resizeEvent(event)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(800, 100, 350, 150)
    window.show()
    window.showBoxes()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: your code answers the question and works perfectly, even with resizing and overlapping. I see you used QRubberBand, which you mentioned to me in another post. Once again, it will take me time to understand how you accomplished this. Thank you.

Comment: @eyllanesc, what happened to your answer? I was hoping to look through how you accomplished that as well.

Comment: @davideps. He based his answer on earlier versions of your question and comments, so perhaps he felt it became redundant. I can see his deleted answer and it basically explains why the cursor-rect wasn't working in your original question - but that is as far as it goes.

Comment: can you explain why you move the cursor to the start and end of a line? When I think of making a bounding box, I only track the leftmost and rightmost "x" and the top and bottom "y".

Comment: @davideps. The only method I found for getting the viewport coords of a position in the text is `cursorRect`. So how could you determine the top-left point *without* moving the cursor to the start of the first line of the highlight? By the same token, how could you determine the bottom-right point without scanning all the highlighted lines to find the longest? If you look at the third box, you will see that the top-left and bottom-right points are not equivalent to the start and end of the highlight. And if the hightlight is extended down to include "wrapped", the rightmost edge will change.

Comment: @davideps. My implementation is mostly dictated by the use of [QRect.united()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qrect.html#united). I look for three rects that cover the top-left, the rightmost-edge and the bottom-edge, and then unite them all.

Comment: OK, thank you. I understand your general approach (though not every line yet).