# Replacing QTextEdit bounding box with a line

Tags: python, pyside, qtextedit

This question is a slight modification of the [bounding box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46911925/getting-the-bounding-box-of-qtextedit-selection) example. I'm trying to understand how to draw simple shapes. I just want to replace the bounding box with a diagonal line from the upperLeft point to the lowerRight point. However, QLine() does not appear to have a show() method and viewport() has no addItem() method. So, I think the line is not being displayed.   Here is my modification of the showBoxes method:

```
def showLines(self):
    while self.boxes:
        self.boxes.pop()            #self.boxes.pop().deleteLater()
                                    #Qline has no deleteLater(). Does that matter?
    viewport = self.edit.viewport()
    for start, end, ident in db:
        rect = self.edit.getBoundingRect(start, end)
        x = rect.x()
        y = rect.y()
        h = rect.height()
        w = rect.width()
        line = QLine()             #QRubberBand(QRubberBand.Rectangle, viewport)
        line.setLine(x,y,x+w,y+h)  #box.setGeometry(rect)
        # need to show line here?
        self.boxes.append(line)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to replace `QRubberBand` with another widget that draws the diagonal, to create a class that inherits from `QWidget` and overwrite the `paintEvent` method.

```
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.edit = TextEditor(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)
        self.boxes = []

    def showBoxes(self):
        while self.boxes:
            self.boxes.pop().deleteLater()
        viewport = self.edit.viewport()
        for start, end, ident in db:
            rect = self.edit.getBoundingRect(start, end)
            box = LineBand(viewport)
            box.setGeometry(rect)
            box.show()
            self.boxes.append(box)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.showBoxes()
        super().resizeEvent(event)


class LineBand(QWidget):
    def  paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.black, 1.8))
        painter.drawLine(self.rect().topLeft(), self.rect().bottomRight())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I understand your general approach but not the details. How did you know that you could (or need to) call `LineBand()` with `viewport`? `LineBand()` is called within `showBoxes`, so it has access to the local `rect` variable? Would you ever want to pass `rect` to `LineBand()` as a parameter?

Comment: @davideps Call it inside showBoxes since this method is called in resizeEvent, and the latter is called every time the window resizes and therefore changes the geometric position of some rectangles, for example if you enlarge the window enough there will be no second row so that the rectangles that were in the second row will vary the y coordinate.

Comment: The coordinates of a widget are always relative to the parent, in this case to viewport (if we do not pass a parent the coordinates will be relative to the screen), when using setGeometry () we are passing the x coordinate, and relative to the parent and the size that it will have, then this parameter can be accessed through the rect (), that is, the rectangle where the widget will be located relative to the parent, for that reason to avoid calculation use that method since QRect () has the topLeft methods ( ) and bottomRight ()

Comment: I understand. Thank you.

Comment: what is the purpose of having both `box.setGeometry(rect)` in showBoxes() and `painter.drawLine(self.rect().topLeft(), self.rect().bottomRight())` in lineBand()? Aren't these statements both determining what is to be drawn to the screen?

Comment: can you explain the difference between `setGeometry` and `painter.drawLine`? Why do I need both?

Comment: @davideps When we pass a parent to a widget then the widget will be located in the upper left of the parent, ie the position (0,0), in conclusion the position of the widget will be in relation to the coordinates of the parent, with setGeometry we indicate that the widget is drawn has the size of the rectangle and the position of the rectangle with respect to the parent. On the other hand, when we paint the widget, it will always be done in the coordinates of the widget. All the above is in the Qt documentation, I recommend you check it before asking someone.