# Overwrite paintEvent of QTextEdit to draw rectangle around word

Tags: python, pyqt5

I use QTextEdit from PyQt5 and I want to put a frame around selected words. As suggested in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72603157/overwrite-paintevent-in-qtextedit-to-draw-rectangle-around-word/72607146?noredirect=1#comment128258931_72607146) I tried to overwrite the paintEvent. The coordinates for the rectangle I want to extract from the cursor position. So, I put the cursor of my TextEditor at the beginning and at the end of the text and then tried to get the global coordinates from each the start and the end. With these coordinates a rectangle should be drawn. But when I run the code, the output coordinates are wrong and only a dash or a very small rectangle is drawn.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTextEdit, QWidget, QApplication, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class TextEditor(QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.coordinates = []

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self.viewport())
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.black, 4, Qt.SolidLine))
        if self.coordinates:
            for coordinate in self.coordinates:
                painter.drawRect(coordinate[0].x(), coordinate[0].y(), coordinate[1].x() - coordinate[0].x(), 10)
        super(TextEditor, self).paintEvent(event)

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        edit = TextEditor(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(edit)
        self.boxes = []
        text = "Hello World"
        edit.setText(text)
        word = "World"
        start = text.find(word)
        end = start + len(word)
        edit.coordinates.append(self.emit_coorindate(start, end, edit))
        edit.viewport().update()

    def emit_coorindate(self, start, end, edit):
        cursor = edit.textCursor()
        cursor.setPosition(start)
        x = edit.cursorRect().topLeft()
        cursor.setPosition(end)
        y = edit.cursorRect().bottomRight()
        return (x, y)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(800, 100, 1000, 1000)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Are the coordinates emitted somewhere in your code? I don’t see where `emit_coordinate` gets called.

Comment: it get's called here `edit.coordinates.append(self.emit_coorindate(start, end, edit))`, in order to add the new coordinates to the list

Comment: That will never work propertly: first of all, you're trying to get the rect when the window is still being initialized (so, the editor hasn't been resized yet, nor the text has been laid out). Then, if the text changes (as pointed out in your previous attempt) or the widget is resized and word wrapping is active (which is the default) the rectangle of the selection won't be updated. What you want to do isn't impossible, but very *difficult*, because text layout *is* complex. I'm in the process of providing an answer to your previous post, but I'm fixing it in my spare time; please be patient.

Comment: Thank you very much, I look forward to your reply. It is very much appreciated!

Comment: @Mazze By the way, please do not create *new* questions that are identical to a previously closed one. Instead, improve (edit) the closed question and add details to point out that you don't agree with the closure (or that the question marked for duplicate doesn't solve the issue, also explaining *why* it's not valid for your needs) and/or eventually use comments to add further details and notify that an update has been made.